# I get this unexpected traceback

Tags: fonts, get

I am trying to write some code and I always get this...

Any idea why this happened?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "grab.py", line 47, in main
    shopImage = Shop.GenerateImage(self, date, shop)
  File "grab.py", line 123, in GenerateImage
    textWidth, _ = font.getsize(date)
  File "C:\Users\migue\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFont.py", line 254, in getsize
    size, offset = self.font.getsize(text, direction, features, language)
TypeError: expected string
```

I am trying to grab the contents of a shop of a game and present it in a simple image.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

one of your parameters is a not a string, look which parameter from the above is not a string:
text, direction, features, language and change it to string